# Explanation of zfill method in Python

Tags: python, hash

I'm using the [ImageHash](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ImageHash) module to get hashes of images. I have this code:

```
hashSize = 8
imghash3 = []
image = "pic1.jpg"

imghash1 = imagehash.phash(Image.open(image))
print(imghash1)
>>>d1d1f1f3f3737373
imghash2 = str(imagehash.phash(Image.open(image), hashSize))
print(imghash2)
>>>11b97c7eb158ac
imghash3.append(bin( int(imghash2, 16))[2:].zfill(64))
print(imghash3)
>>>['0000000000010001101110010111110001111110101100010101100010101100']
```

So `imagehash1` is the basic usage of the module.

Now what I don't understand is what kind of transformation the `hashSize` made to the original string in `imagehash2` and how the 3rd function convert the `imagehash2` into a 64 bit string.

Comment: *"this line"* is what line? Please don't write a meaningless title like that and then even make it wrong by posting more than a line.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't really know how to describe it. Can you suggest me a more clear title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During `phash` computation original image is resized. `hashSize` parameter basically controls height and width of resized image.

Algorithm can be found  [here](http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/432-Looks-Like-It.html). Implementation of the first step (reduce size):

```
image = image.convert("L").resize((hash_size, hash_size), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

See sources of [`imagehash.phash`](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/imagehash/blob/master/imagehash/__init__.py#L116)

---

Lets see what the line `imghash3.append(bin( int(imghash2, 16))[2:].zfill(64))` does.

```
In [16]: imghash2 = '11b97c7eb158ac'
```

First of all it converts hexadecimal string into integer

```
In [17]: int(imghash2, 16)
Out[17]: 4989018956716204
```

The builtin [`bin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) function is applied to convert the integer into a binary string

```
In [18]: bin( int(imghash2, 16))
Out[18]: '0b10001101110010111110001111110101100010101100010101100'
```

Drops first two characters using [list slice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/471899)

```
In [19]: bin( int(imghash2, 16))[2:]
Out[19]: '10001101110010111110001111110101100010101100010101100'
```

[Adds `0`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=zfill#str.zfill) on the left side to make a string of 64 characters total

```
In [20]: bin( int(imghash2, 16))[2:].zfill(64)
Out[20]: '0000000000010001101110010111110001111110101100010101100010101100'
```